# Macro outlook, automatizar correo electronico

Tags: vba, macros, outlook

buenas tardes estimados, quisiera saber si existe una forma o metodo ya sea por VBA u otro medio por el cual a cierta hora Outlook me abra en automatico una hoja de correo nva y que este proceso sea en automatico y consecutivamente.

es decir que si estoy trabajando en la computadora y se me olvide mandar lo que necesito que en automatico Outlook interrumpa, o me mande directo al correo a redactar a esa hra.

Answer (score 1):

Primero asigna un recordatorio al mensaje. Para detalles consulta [Agregar o quitar un aviso para un mensaje de correo electrónico o contacto](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Agregar-o-quitar-un-aviso-para-un-mensaje-de-correo-electr%C3%B3nico-o-contacto-ae5bc786-d60b-476f-ac63-7b94cc5a4f42?ui=es-ES&rs=es-ES&ad=ES).

Para que automáticamente se realice una acción luego de occurrido el evento de recordatorio, usa [Application.Reminder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/office/ff870058.aspx).

Ejemplo tomado del enlace (he eliminado saltos de línea para ahorrar espacio)

> En este ejemplo de Microsoft Visual Basic para aplicaciones (VBA) se
>   muestra el elemento que desencadena el evento **Reminder** cuando se
>   desencadena el evento. El código de ejemplo debe ubicarse en un módulo
>   de clase y se debe llamar a la rutina de Initialize_handler antes de
>   que el procedimiento de evento puede ser llamado por Microsoft
>   Outlook.
>
> ```
> Dim WithEvents myolapp As Outlook.Application 
>
> Sub Initialize_handler() 
>  Set myolapp = Outlook.Application      
> End Sub 
>
> Private Sub myolapp_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object) 
>  Item.Display 
> End Sub
> ```